# Type casting in exceptions

Tags: c++

Let's say I Have this:

```
namespace MyNamespace{

class Exception : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
  explicit Exception(const std::string &msg) : std::runtime_error(msg) {}
};

} //namespace MyNamespace
```

And there is a code somewhere in my program:

```
try{
    foo();
}
catch (const MyNamespace::Exception &exc){
    std::cout << exc.what();
}
```

The question is (I want you to examine me) - will I catch the exception if I write in foo:

1) `throw MyNamespace::Exception("Hello world!");`

Here i think, yes, I will, because I definitely pointed out the type of exception(and it's necessary couse of "explicit" keyword) and std::string doesn't have "explicit" keyword which means I can throw "Hello world!" instead of std::string("Hello world!")

2) `throw MyNamespace::Exception(std::string("Hello world!"));`

obviosly, I will.

3) `throw "Hello world!";`

here i think, no, I won't, cause of keyword "explicit" presence.

4) `throw std::string("Hello world");`

no (same reason)

and 5) Whould I catch expections from the 3-4 cases if I didn't have explicit keyword? (I think yes)

update:
6) When the temporary object std::string will be created? At what point of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answers for 1-4 are correct, but the reasoning behind them is a little off.

3) This has nothing to do with `explicit` keyword. The type of the expression after `throw` is `const char[12]` and by the rules the type of the exception thrown is `const char*`.

4) Again, nothing to do with `explicit` string constructors, really. The type thrown is `std::string` and only `std::string` (with reference or not) type of handler can catch it.

5) So obviously, no.

6) When the exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I didnt realize the answer to 6th question: why it will be created when the exception is _thrown_ and not is _cought_? Are we talking about std::string right?

Comment: Because the language spec says so. The catch clause wouldn't know what type of object to create, since a single handler can match several different throw expressions. Whether we're talking about `std::string` or not isn't really relevant.

Comment: Ahh, I meant a little different thing. When the temporary object std::string will be created in case of we throw just const char[x] like "Hello world!".

Comment: It won't be. If you say `throw "Hello"` what's thrown is `const char*`, not `std::string`. In any case, the temporary object that's thrown is initialized immediately when the `throw-expression` executes.

Comment: It won't be, cause of "no conversion is every performed, except a conversion to base class" like Konrad Rudolph said, right?

Comment: No, that's not the reason. Konrad is talking about catching. When throwing, there are conversion - from `T[]` to `T*` and from function to pointer to function.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Just 1 more question :) Are there the situations for rational usage of function throwing? (when it converts to function pointer)

Comment: I doubt it :) Here's what you could do instead of call virtual function `what()` like standard exception classes do: [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0aa6b80e0e21805).

Answer (score 2):

From the wording in 3-5, you're obviously thinking that C++ attempts to match the `throw` to the `catch` statements as if it were picking the best match from overloaded functions to call.  That's not the case.  The `throw` statement is considered separately from any `catch` statements - indeed, you can compile the function `foo` and its `throw` statements before the catching code is written, so it can't choose to convert a `std::string` to some type the catching code ends up looking for... it might not know about that.

The type of value thrown depends entirely on the type of the parameter to `throw`, as it would be understood in the surrounding context if the expression appeared without `throw`.  For example:

```
void foo()
{
     ...
     throw XXX;
}
```

...throws the same type as...

```
void foo()
{
     ...
     auto what_will_be_thrown = XXX;
     throw what_will_be_thrown;
}
```

Conversions like `const char*` to `std::string` are *not* applied when catching, although you can catch a derived type via a public base class (for references or pointers), and of course you can catch types using `const` references etc..

Re 6) - whatever the type of the value, it's created just before the `Exception` constructor is called, just as any for any other function call timing wise, but in this case the object being thrown may be constructed in a separate memory area from the normal call stack, such that it will survive the stack unwinding that happens while looking for a matching catch statement.  Exactly how this is orchestrated by the compiler is not specified in the Standard though.

Comment: It seems very detailed and cognitive answer, thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your rationale for 3 and 4 is wrong, and consequently, so is your answer to 5. Here’s why:

When you `catch` an exception, no conversion is every performed, except a conversion to base class. So `catch (Foo const&)` will never catch anything convertible to `Foo`, except subclasses of `Foo`. It’s for *that* reason, and not related to `explicit` constructors, that your code won’t catch a thrown `std::string` or `char[]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I got it now.